# How to reset JRate Star to zero manually jRate Jquery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

when i click on 3rd star the 3rd star is highligted then.but when i click on reset button to reset star to zero value mean no star is selected i have tried to do this but it creats a new 5 five next to previous 5 stars..
Here is my code

```
$(".jRate").jRate({

        onSet: function(rating) {

            alert(rating);
       }
});

On reset button
$('.reset').on('click',function(){
          $(".jRate").jRate({
             rating: 0,

          });
});
```

So it shows now 10 stars totaly how to should i get only 5 stars when i click on reset button and no star should be selected mean Stars must be reset.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jRate's documentation is not elaborate. I had the same problem too. You can solve it by using the setRating() function.

```
var x = $(".jRate").jRate({

    onSet: function(rating) {

        alert(rating);
   }
});

$('.reset').on('click',function(){
    x.setRating(0);
});
```

The above code will solve your problem. 
I know it is a late reply but hopefully this solution would help others :)

Comment: Thanks @Gsm for the help